# The GTKMM isn't working with my CLion install (Windows 10). CMakeLists.txt - Could not find PkgConfig

Tags: c++, windows, cmake, clion

I have what's probably a beginner's question for you: I'm trying to get Gtk to run with CLion in a windows environment.

I've run through this: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gtkmm/MSWindows a few times (to confirm I did it correctly), added a few things to my system PATH settings, as well as attempting to manipulate the CMakeLists.txt files in CLion and it doesn't seem to be able to find the library. I've been on stackoverflow posing my problem in different ways and trying a few solutions, but no luck as of yet.

Is using gtk headers in CLion possible?

I get the following error attempting to run a program with gtkmm headers: fatal error: gtkmm/application.h: No such file or directory

My CMakeLists.txt looks like the below:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(Kmeans)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE "/usr/bin/pkg-config")
add_executable(Kmeans main.cpp)

find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(GTKMM gtkmm-3.0)

include_directories(${GTKMM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GTKMM_LIBRARY_DIRS})

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} ${GTKMM_LIBRARIES})
```

What generally occurs is that I receive an error reading as follows:

> CMake Error at C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion
>   2018.3.4/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.14/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:510 (message):
>
> -- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)    pkg-config tool not found

Edit to reflect comments and continued efforts:

I have run pacman -S pkg-config as the wiki page suggests, and I can see a pkg-config in my C:\msys64\var\lib\pacman\local folder. Within the toolchain in CLion, the environment is MinGW and CMake is designated to autodetect the compiler, which is in MINGW\mingw32\bin\g++.exe.

I've also confirmed that my executable is in usr/bin/pkg-config using Cygwin terminal and added set(PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE "/usr/bin/pkg-config") to my cmake file after going through the answer provided by @Isuru Walpola here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/717302/cmake-could-not-find-pkgconfig-missing-pkg-config-executable

Unfortunately, I still receive the same error message.

Additionally, I tried a complete reinstall of CLion, as well as switching my environment to Cygwin, using its setup file to install any library/doc/development tools referencing gtk3 (and below) that I could find. CLion also pre-populates the names for this when I begin typing #include <> statements, however they're not found as soon as the full include statement is written.

I no longer receive the pkg-config not found error, but rather than CLion cannot locate these particular GTK libraries and header files.

My CMakeLists.txt now looks like the below. There is some duplication and unusable lines that I've included for testing as I don't really understand some of the commands.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project(ProjectKMeans)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(PKG_CONFIG_PATH /usr/lib/pkgconfig)
set(PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE /usr/bin/pkg-config.exe)
add_executable(ProjectKMeans main.cpp)

find_package(PkgConfig)

pkg_check_modules(GTKMM gtkmm-3.0)
pkg_check_modules(gtk gtkmm-3.0)
PKG_CHECK_MODULES(GTK GTK)
ADD_DEFINITIONS(${GTKMM_CFLAGS_OTHER})
include_directories(${GTKMM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${GTKMM_LIBRARY_DIRS})

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} ${GTKMM_LIBRARIES})
```

I think the problem is that GTKMM is not recognized. I don't understand this naming convention. None of the libraries have this name that I'm aware of. What am I missing?

Comment: The [wiki page](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gtkmm/MSWindows) you refers to is about MSYS/MinGW environments. Have you run `pacman -S pkg-config` as the wiki page suggests? If you use CLion for configure the project, then you need to select appropriate toolchain. Please, show the beginning of the configuration log, where generator and compilers are listed.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have run this, and I can see a pkg-config in my C:\msys64\var\lib\pacman\local folder.   Within the toolchain in CLion, it looks like I only have MinGW available here. I'm not sure where to locate the configuration log, but in this toolchain section CMake is designated to autodetect the compiler, which is in MINGW\mingw32\bin\g++.exe

Comment: I've also confirmed that my executable is in usr/bin/pkg-config using Cygwin terminal and added set(PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE "/usr/bin/pkg-config") to my cmake file after going through the answer provided by @Isuru Walpola here (though I admit I am trying things blindly at this point): https://askubuntu.com/questions/717302/cmake-could-not-find-pkgconfig-missing-pkg-config-executable. No luck.

Comment: Well, your comments provide important information about your problem. Please, [edit] your question post and incorporate this information into it. On Stack Overflow we expect the **question post** to contain all information about the problem. In opposite, the *comments* are temporary things, they serve only for *request* that information.

Comment: Ok thank you. I've added these points to my post. I misread the comment etiquette instruction provided below